# Hide RAT in a picture link in a document?

Tags: rat

Is this possible?  A friend tried to install a rat by sending me a file that looked like `049.jpg.exe` but i didnt click on it cuz of the .exe in the end.

This was just for fun but it made me Wonder, can you hide a rat completely so The victim doesn't see The .exe?

If I wanted to give him a rat,  would it be possible to make a custom link and hide The rat in it so when he Clicks it he get infected without notice?  Like send him an email " your picture `www.facebook.com/089jpg-anthonynude` is violating our rules and we does not tolerate nude or pornographic content. / Facebook "

Answer (score 3):

You can't trick Facebook, because it looks into the file contents to determine its type. Moreover, pictures uploaded are automatically converted into another format.

Historically there was a related vulnerability in some versions of Windows, which simplified `.jpg.exe` tricks. If you included an RTL (right-to-left) character in the filename, it would be parsed right to left, so a file named as `exe.something.jpg` is seemingly a JPG file for the user, but it executes when clicked on.

Besides this, I don't know any other possibilities that a file with the right jpg extension would execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, provided there is a bug in the image viewing software which allows for remote code execution.  See https://imagetragick.com for a recent example of such a bug.